# How to find characteristic polynomial of matrices by python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix. I want to calculate the characteristic polynomial of $A$ i.e. I want to calculate
$$det(XI-A)$$.

Is there any function which computes this in python?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like you are interested in a symbolic solution? The characteristic polynomial doesn't make much sense numerically, where you would probably be more interested in the eigenvalues. To obtain the characteristic polynomial of a symbolic matrix `M` in SymPy you want to use the `M.charpoly` method.

For more information, see the SymPy documentation on matrices and linear algebra: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html

If you want to find the eigenvalues of a numpy array, `numpy.linalg.eigvals` (or `numpy.linalg.eigvalsh` if you have a Hermitian matrix) is what you want.

Comment: thank you. It realy helped. Is there any differences between numpy and sympy

Comment: Yes, they target two fundamentally different problems. Numpy is intended for numerical calculations, i. e., calculations involving raw numbers, and is especially efficient for that (for a Python module, that is). SymPy, on the other hand, is like Maple or Mathematica and doesn't provide efficient numerical algorithms, but rather exploits Python's fundamental object structure, to allow dynamic creation of symbolic expressions. Using `sympy.lambdify` on these expressions, you can convert them into numpy functions, however, which has some very useful use cases in certain areas of science.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` does handle the polynomials pretty well thanks to the [Polynomial API](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.package.html). Since the characteristic polynomial of a matrix M is uniquely defined by its roots, it's totally possible to compute it using the `fromroots` class method of the `Polynomial` object:

```py
import numpy as np

def characteristic_polynomial(M: np.ndarray) -> np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial:
    return np.polynomial.Polynomial.fromroots(np.linalg.eigvals(M))
```

Calling this function on `np.array([[0, 1],[-1, 0]])` returns a `Polynomial` object with coefficients `[1.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 1.+0.j]`, which is expected since the characteristic polynomial of this matrix is X² + 1.

Note that if the matrix is Hermitian (or symmetric real), using [`np.linalg.eigvalsh`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigvalsh.html) is the preferred way of computing the eigenvalues.